# Swipe action sometimes "jumps" to end of the screen

Tags: swift, tableview, uiswipeactionsconfiguration

I am using swipeAction in my app and sometimes you can see UI bug. Sometimes it "jumps" at the end of the screen. I don't really know how to describe it, so there is video: https://youtu.be/AG4vGxVD4c8

Is it something in my code? (Swift 4.2)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let favouriteAction = self.favouriteAction(forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
    let swipeConfig = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [favouriteAction])
    return swipeConfig
}

func favouriteAction(forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {

    let starship = allStarships[indexPath.row].name
    let isFav = LibraryAPI.shared.isFavourite(starshipName: starship)

    let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil) { (action, view, completion) in

        if isFav {
            LibraryAPI.shared.removeStarshipFromFavourites(starshipName: starship)
            self.allStarships[indexPath.row].isFavourte = false
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        } else {
            LibraryAPI.shared.addStarshipToFavourites(starshipName: starship)
            self.allStarships[indexPath.row].isFavourte = true
            self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
        }

        completion(true)
    }

    action.backgroundColor = UIColor.starWarsColor.darkBlue
    action.image = isFav ? UIImage(named: "favourite") : UIImage(named: "unfavourite")
    return action
}
```

**Edit:**
added more methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let starshipsNames = LibraryAPI.shared.getUsersStarshipsNames()

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "starshipCell", for: indexPath) as! StarshipTableViewCell

    cell.name.text = allStarships[indexPath.row].name
    cell.model.text = allStarships[indexPath.row].model
    cell.manufacturer.text = allStarships[indexPath.row].manufacturer

    if let cellName = cell.name.text {
        if starshipsNames.contains(cellName) {
            cell.setAsUsers(isUsers: true)
        } else {
            cell.setAsUsers(isUsers: false)
        }
    }

    cell.setFavourite(isFavourite: allStarships[indexPath.row].isFavourte ?? false)


    if indexPath.row == allStarships.count - 1 { // last cell
        loadMoreItems()
    }

    return cell
}
```

In StarshipTableViewCell:
It seems that awakeFromNib() is never called (I tried to put print into the method).

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addSubview(favouriteImage)
    self.addSubview(starshipImage)
    self.addSubview(name)
    self.addSubview(model)
    self.addSubview(manufacturer)
    layoutSetup()

}

func setAsUsers(isUsers: Bool) {
    if isUsers {
        starshipImage.image = UIImage(named: "sw-starship")!
        starshipImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.starWarsColor.darkBlue
        starshipImage.tintColor = UIColor.starWarsColor.yellow
    } else {
        starshipImage.image = UIImage(named: "sw-starship-angle")!
        starshipImage.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        starshipImage.tintColor = UIColor.starWarsColor.darkBlue
    }
}

func setFavourite(isFavourite: Bool) {
    if isFavourite {
        favouriteImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.starWarsColor.darkBlue
    } else {
        favouriteImage.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You may delay the update of tablerow in the action. Then try again.

Comment: We need more information. Can we see your tableview cellForRowAt? It looks like your tableview is removing a row and then adding one back in.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I added methods. I tried also change "trailingSwipe" to "leadingSwipe", but it's still happening

Comment: Can it be because of pagination?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?